# ffmpeg watermark: scale2ref output can't be used in second overlay

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark, video-editing, video-watermarking

I was able to add a watermark to 2 position(top left & bottom right) of a video with scaling image height to tenth of the video height in one command

```sh
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i /path/to/input.mp4 -i /path/to/watermark.jpg -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih/10[logo-out][video-out];[video-out][logo-out]overlay=10:10[flag];[1:v][flag]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih/10[logo-out2][video-out2];[video-out2][logo-out2]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10" -c:a copy /path/to/output.mp4
```

But the above command is too redundant, so I remove the second `scale2ref`

```sh
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i /path/to/input.mp4 -i /path/to/watermark.jpg -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih/10[logo-out][video-out];[video-out][logo-out]overlay=10:10[flag];[flag][logo-out]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10" -c:a copy /path/to/output.mp4
```

But sadly, error occurs

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb195013c00] Invalid stream specifier: logo-out.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Stream specifier 'logo-out' in filtergraph description [1:v][0:v]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih/10[logo-out][video-out];[video-out][logo-out]overlay=10:10[flag];[flag][logo-out]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10 matches no streams
```

I know error occurs because of the first overlay didn't set an image output specifier, but it seems we can't do this? I only know overlay can set a video stream specifier.

How can I use the `[logo-out]` specifier which output from scale2ref in the second overlay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An output generated inside a filtergraph can only be consumed once. To reuse it, split it first.

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -i /path/to/input.mp4 -i /path/to/watermark.jpg -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih/10[logo-out][video-out];[logo-out]split=2[logo-left][logo-right];[video-out][logo-left]overlay=10:10[flag];[flag][logo-right]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10" -c:a copy /path/to/output.mp4`

Comment: Thank you, it works. I'm new in ffmpeg, I don't know I can use split.